# Buzzer does not give a sound when GPIO pin is high

Tags: embedded, stm32f4

I'm new here and have some issues about my stm32f429 project.
I would like to drive a buzzer when flame sensor detect a flame and it does not work fine. So can anyone help me to resolve this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: you will need to tell us more about the buzzer, its type, datasheet, etc

Comment: Probably the GPIO pin cannot source enough current to get it to work. Check the voltage on the pin when it is supposed to be high.

Comment: Also, I think a buzzer needs to have a PWM kind of signal instead of continuous high to work.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Can you elaborate the "problem" ?

Comment: Use a Piezo buzzer rather than magnetic  relay type

Comment: Hello, it's a active buzzer with 3 pin (VCC and GND and I/O pin). See the link .

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=passive+buzzer&rlz=1C1CHBF_frFR741FR741&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8_Jqm9vjZAhXGsaQKHTP9BOwQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=637#imgrc=vx_fUR5-H6ZglM:

Comment: My Programme looks like :

Comment: Your link shows a "passive" buzzer, with a transistor as amplifier of a GPIO. It needs a square wave at 2-5kHz to emit any sound.

Comment: @zinhom69: Please put all the information required to answer your question into the actual question - not sprinkled through the comments. That way your readers will have all they need in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Your link shows a "passive" buzzer, with a transistor as amplifier of a GPIO. It needs a square wave at 2-5kHz to emit any sound.

Comment: Hello Ali, i think i should creat a PWM square wave and integrate it to my project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, i will try this solution and i well tell you back if this resolve my issues.

Comment: @zinhom69, note, that this is not a full "PWM", you need to generate a square wave, 50% PWM only.